# jQuery load has visual side effects, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, innerhtml

I'm writing an app that loads in content via ajax using the jQuery.load function. 
The problem that I'm running into is that there are visual "leftovers" from the previous content on the page that I can't seem to eliminate without some little hacks.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should probably post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can clean out the previous contents first:

```
$('#divId').html('').load(...);
```

...or something along those lines.

Comment: something along those lines might be right, but that specific idea doesn't solve it. The problem happens unpredictably, but nonsense like `$('body').html($('body').html())` seems to do the trick. The leftover pixels are where the content spilled out of the container a bit. I might settle with this though because it's a stupid problem that I don't want to spend all week solving

Comment: actually they way I just mentioned slows the page a bit, so I'm not going to use it.

Comment: If you don't post the code, don't expect more specific help. What is spilling over what elements?